# Chrome Extension for Amazon Cloud

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-web-services, google-chrome-extension

Is there any extension for chrome which is similar to Hybridfox or Elasticfox?

Answer (score 4):

You can use AWS web console from Amazon to do the same things from Google Chrome.
As of now there is nothing similar to Elastifox on Google Chrome.

Comment: That is true but how about Eucalyputs. There is no amazon kind of UI for Eucalyptus.

Answer (score 0):

There is this Chrome Extension:

[elastic-chrome](http://code.google.com/p/elastic-chrome/)

But it does **not** seem to be actively developed, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So there is Eucalyptus.

It is an abstraction layer between EC2 and your virtualized hardware.  It is also an abstraction layer between physical hardware, KVM, VMWare, etc and your VM operating systems.  Feasible.  Unfortunately if you left VMWare for KVM, Xen, etc. for the performance gains then you are literally destroying these benefits so that your infrastructure team can assign quotas instead of provisioning things as the company needs, or actively managing environments and the costs associated with them.  If you are on physical hardware then welcome to the wild world of virtualization.  You should evaluate virtual Iron (Oracle VM) now since its free and you need to catch up.

Unless your infrastructure team/guy is outnumbered by your applications and development personnel by a ratio of at least 10 to 1 this is completely manageable and is supposed to be their job.  Otherwise then assigning quotas would be a great idea, although it would be a decent performance drain (tell me I am wrong with references please.)

It would be worth your time to look at Chef (Puppet sucks.)  Knife has EC2, KVM, VMWare, et al provisioning capabilities to spin up an entire node and everything you want on it from a simple CLI command.

As for browser extensions, there are quite a few Amazon cloud management tools available for Firefox.  Unfortunately since Google and Amazon are now competing against one another there are very few quality tools for Chrome.  I use Chrome as my primary browser, Firefox for tools that arent controversial, and IE/Safari when there is no other option.